# Show that there is a random variable with the given characteristic function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here is an old qual problem that has me bamboozled.  Any hints or solutions would be appreciated
[image]

Here's my thoughts: The given characteristic function looks very similar to the characteristic function of a poisson distribution. And if you integrate it over the first measure given in the hint, then you get the characteristic function of a poisson distribution.  But then how do you use this fact to extend to a general $
mu$?  it's also not clear to me what the significance of the other two special cases are in the hint.

Source: https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Fall_2012/20123_507a.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If $\mu$ is a finite measure then you can prove the result as follows: let $r=\mu (0,\infty)$ and $\lambda = \frac {\mu} r$. Let $\{X_i\}$ be i.i.d. with distribution $\lambda$ and N be Poisson with parameter r, independent of $\{X_i\}$ . An easy calculation (involving conditioning on N) show that $\phi$ is the characteristic function of $X_1+X_2+...+X_N$. For the general case you can use the continuity theorem for characteristic functions: the hypothesis implies that the restriction $\mu _n$ of $\mu$ to $(1/n,\infty$) is a finite measure. The characteristic function of $\mu_n$ converges to $\phi$ pointwise and $\phi$ is continuous by a simple application of Dominated Convergence Theorem. I am sorry that I didn't use the hints, but the result is standard and my proof is also standard.

Comment: I'm not seeing how it is the characteristic function of $X_1+...+X_N$ Could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: $Ee^{it(X_1+...+X_N)} = E(Ee^{it(X_1+...+X_N)}|N)$ =$\sum  (E{e^{itX_1))^{n}} P\{N=n\}}$=$\sum _n(Ee^{itX_1})^{n} e^{-r} \frac {r^{n}} {n!}$. Just sum this exponential series and you will get the exact expression you are looking for.